# Relation between $\operatorname{mod}p$ and $\operatorname{mod}p+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

let $ a \equiv x \pmod{p}, \\ a \equiv y \pmod{p + 1}$

Is there some relation between $x$ and $y$.
Maybe like $f(x) = y$.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: @JohnWhite not necessarily .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly but here's one answer.

$a = k_1p + x$ and $a = k_2(p+1) + y = k_2p + k_2 + y$ for some $k_1, k_2$

Therefore $x \equiv k_2 + y \equiv \lfloor \frac{a}{p+1}\rfloor + y \pmod p$

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, every single combination of $0\leq x<p$ and $0\leq y<p+1$ is possible, and any such $(x,y)$ pair uniquely corresponds to some
$$
a\equiv z\pmod{p(p+1)}
$$
with $0\leq z<p(p+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

We hsve:

$$x(p+1)-yp \equiv a \mod p(p+1)$$

so

$$x \equiv \frac{a+yp}{p+1} \mod p(p+1)$$